# Extracting data from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath

I am brand new to Ruby and Xpath. I need to extract the System features from the table at

http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1

So far I have tried targeting all of the td tags, the page doesn't use CSS ids so I cant target that way.

I tried the following code

```
doc.xpath('//tr/th/span[normalize-space(text())="System features"]/..')
```

but it returns nothing ;(

Does anyone have any idea the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That expression should work fine on the given source, but it's not really idiomatic. You probably want to use something more like this:

```
//tr/th[span[normalize-space()='System features']
```

1. `normalize-space` expects a string argument. Passing the node-set returned by `text()` forces conversion to a string by taking the first text node in document order. This doesn't really matter in your document, because there's only one child text node, but you should be aware that this is what's happening.
2. You don't need to backtrack up the tree using `/..` at the end of the expression. You can test for the presence of the child `span` using a nested predicate and thereby select the desired `th` directly.

If you want to exploit the fact that the target `th` contains only the one child `span` node, you could write this simplified expression:

```
//tr/th[normalize-space(span)='System features']
```

So, why isn't working? Hard to tell, but it could be because the tool you're using to parse the document is creating a structure that differs from how it appears in the literal source (e.g. because the input isn't really well-formed XML). Try a slightly different expression:

```
//*[span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='System features']]
```

Or maybe you should first verify that you can retrieve the `span` itself, then build the expression up from that:

```
//span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='System features']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I run the second last code segment I get irb(main):406:0*
<'//*[span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='System features']]')
SyntaxError: (irb):407: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
...ath('//*[span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='Syst...
...                               ^
(irb):407: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting $end
...' and normalize-space()='System features']]')
...                               ^
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: @Ninja2k - I used single quotes in my expression, but you used single quotes to *surround* the expression, too. You can't use single quotes in both. Just switch to double quotes in one or the other.

Comment: Cool thanks for that, ok so I have added doc.xpath("//*[span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='System features']]") which then looks like it outputs the Nokogiri array? I can add .text to output and it gives me the first value "System Features" , how can I get the rest of the values?

Comment: Is Nokogiri only returning the content of system features cell itself? I entered the following doc.xpath("//*[span[@class='themebody' and normalize-space()='System features']]").each do | method_span | 
puts method_span.path
end                                                                     and that returns to me /html/body/table[5]/tr/td[3]/table[5]/tr/td/table[1]/tr[1]/th                                                                    if I am correct in my observation does that mean I need to write a line for every cell or is there an easier way to do it?